# Google Tag Manager isn't tracking mobile click to calls

Tags: debugging, google-analytics, triggers, google-tag-manager

I am trying to track clicks on the phone number on the website. After I set up the trigger using following settings:

> Trigger Type: all elements;
>
> Page URL: contains "tel:" ;
>
> Click Text: contains "13";

With these settings, the trigger is firing correctly on the desktop but isn't working on mobile.

I tried to use only "Page URL"/"Text Only"/"Form Text"/"Form contains" as conditions for the trigger to fire, but all attempts are unsuccessful. I also tried to use "Just Links" as a trigger type but it's not helping.

I also tested the URL in different mobile browsers (chrome/safari) and emulator. With an emulator, the tag is firing correctly but it's not working on the

Please have a look at the preview to see the page and tracking I am talking about:

https://www.googletagmanager.com/start_preview/gtm?uiv2&id=GTM-T92J432&gtm_auth=MmNY2ZtOefQOp1Kce4yUFQ&gtm_preview=env-5&gtm_debug=x&url=https://lp.acfc.com.au/good-credit

I appreciate your advice on what is the problem and how it can be fixed.

Thanks!
Kirill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, better way of doing this to set generic trigger in GTM, then you will be able to track any phones on your website:

1) Enable built-in variable Click Element (if you already have it, you can skip this step)
[image]

2) Create trigger, which will fire for all links which have `tel:*****` (it can be any phone).
[image]
CSS selector on the screenshot is `a[href*="tel:"]`

3) Create a tag, which will send data to GA

[image]

4) Check your events in GA.

*Keep in mind that it might take a couple of hours to appear in Behaviour-> Events tab. Or you can check it immediately in Real Time -> Events tab*

Comment: Hi Victor, Spasibo for a great suggestion!

Comment: @KirillKonovalov If this worked for you, can you upvote and accept it as the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I just found out that in order to identify an event it is safer to look at how the data layer is changing after the action rather than on the "Variable" tab.

By doing so, you can see what data is actually going to google analytics, and it is more stable to use it as an ID for a trigger to fire.

In my case, I've had only elementURL that was pushed back to the datalayer. I used the parameter elementID equals "tel:xxxxxx" to make the tracker work. Hope it will help (just put your number instead of x).

Cheers!